# How to change the text color of a fadeIn div?

Tags: jquery

I have the following working script that run on load.

```
$("div.fadeinWrapper").fadeIn(3000);
```

When the fadeIn is completed, I want to use **animate** function to change the color of a span inside the div, from #000000 to #FF0000. How I do that?

Comment: Call `animate` in `fadeIn`'s complete callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$("div.fadeinWrapper").fadeIn(3000, function() {
    $("span.yourclass").animate({
        color: "#fff000",
    });
});
```

Note: you need the [Jquery UI library](http://jqueryui.com/) for this.

More info on `animate()`: http://jqueryui.com/animate/

Comment: Thank you Joren, this is exactl what I was looking for :) and of course I was missing the jquery ui library.

Answer (score 1):

fadeIn() has a callback function

```
 $("div.fadeinWrapper").fadeIn(3000, function() {
    --your animate code here--
 });
```

source : http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Comment: Thanks imbask, I was just looking for the middle part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) callback to animate the span element but the [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method by default does not support animation of colors.

You need to include [jQuery color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) library or jQuery UI library for that

```
$("div.fadeinWrapper").fadeIn(3000, function(){
    $(this).find('span').animate({
        color: '#FF0000'
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wg6Av/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example which will help you in understanding the code. Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hEmCa/1/

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#pt').click(function(){
     $('#d').fadeIn(6000);
         $('#d1').animate({
         opacity: 0.65,
          left: "+=500",
          height: "toggle"
         });
     });
  });
```

I hope you wanted to achieve this.